# Facebook sharing not working propely

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, facebook-sharer

I set parameters such as picture and name but it not displaying name of the pet and other information below is given a preview of sharing. why both previews are different and why not displaying some data please help me how can I resolve this error and thanks in advance.

Link - 1

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=241670762980516&link=http://newseinstein.com/Rwork/index.php/Pet/view/105&picture=http://newseinstein.com/Rwork/uploads/405517413/img1.jpeg&name=scarpy/Airedale%20Terrier/Lost&caption=www.hero-pet.com&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com&display=popup

Link - 2

> https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=241670762980516&link=http://newseinstein.com/Rwork/index.php/Pet/view/104&picture=http://newseinstein.com/Rwork/uploads/723253718/img1.jpeg&name=Please%20Help%20Me/Aegean%20cat/Found&caption=www.hero-pet.com&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com&display=popup

Comment: Facebook is removing all ways to set this data dynamically on runtime, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations

Answer (score 0):

The best way is Instead of passing link directly in `href` tag Use some custom facebook developer jquery to share your post or page with the image.

For example, your `a` tag is like

```
<a id="fb_id" class="facebook" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

and then you may use custom developer script like following,

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : IP, // ADD YOUR appID
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.5'
  });
};

(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

window.onload = function(){
 document.getElementById('fb_id').onclick = function() {
  FB.ui({
    method: 'share', // YOU MAY SET YOUR METHOD HERE feed OR share
    href: DOMAIN, // ADD YOUR DOMAIN NAME HERE WHICH YOU HAVE ADDED WHILE CREATING NEW APP.
  }, function(response){});
};

};
```

It will sure display data with an image while sharing your page.

NOTE: IT MAY BE NOT WORK IN YOUR LOCAL ENVIRONMENT.